# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pendingTaskDonePromise')

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am using Jenkins to run some tests. We seem to get some errors after updating to the latest version of testcafe.

```
12:13:30 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pendingTaskDonePromise')
12:13:30     at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/uptests_testcafeeII/node_modules/testcafe/src/runner/index.js:183:75
12:13:30     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
12:13:30     at Runner._getTaskResult (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/uptests_testcafeeII/node_modules/testcafe/src/runner/index.js:183:41)
```

Does anyone have an idea what this could be and how we could fix this?
This happens immediatly after we start the test, occurs a couple of times per day. The next run will just work again as it should.

Answer (score 1):

The TestCafe team will be happy to assist you with this issue. So, please create a separate thread in the official TestCafe repository using the following link: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&projects=&template=bug_report.yaml.

Also, refer to the following help topic before submitting the issue: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402636/faq/general-info#how-to-create-a-minimal-working-example-when-you-submit-an-issue.

Answer (score 0):

Added the following issue - for crosslinking

https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/7805